# SendKeys not working?

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    CheckBox1.Checked = True
    While CheckBox1.Checked = True
        SendKeys("{END}")
    End While
End Sub
```

That is the code, the error is "SendKeys is a type and cannot be used as an expression."
How could I fix this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    CheckBox1.Checked = True
    While CheckBox1.Checked = True
        SendKeys.Send("{END}")
    End While
End Sub
```

You need to refer SendKeys.Send();

Answer (score 1):

Use `SendKeys.Send("{END}",True)`